# Can I rename a file inside an iso image without completely rebuilding it?

Tags: bash, windows, uefi, iso, disk-image

I have a bash script that is supposed to download a Windows 10 iso file from Microsoft and then change the names of two files in that iso in order to remove the "Press any key to boot from this CD/DVD..." prompt.

Essentially I just want to swap the file names of these two files:

[image]

So `cdboot.efi` becomes `cdboot_noprompt.efi`.
And `cdboot_noprompt.efi` becomes `cdboot.efi`.

I know I could mount the image, copy the the contents somewhere, modify it to my liking and then use `mkisofs`/`genisoimage` to create a new iso, somewhat like this:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /path/to/windows.iso /mnt
sudo cp /mnt/ /mnt_copy/
cd /mnt_copy/efi/microsoft/boot
sudo mv cdboot.efi tmp.efi
sudo mv cdboot_noprompt.efi cdboot.efi
sudo mv tmp.efi cdboot_noprompt.efi
sudo genisoimage -J -joliet-long -r -allow-lowercase -allow-multidot -o "/path/to/new/windows.iso" "/mnt_copy/"
# And then magically make the iso bootable again. No idea how this would be done.
```

but I'd like to avoid all this unnecessary overhead.

Comment: ISO images are read-only.  Also, you say you already have a script for doing this?

Comment: You have to use special tools. Google "iso image editor"

Comment: @Kusalananda They may be read-only according to the specification, but maybe there is still a way to modify it. I mean you could definitely change arbitrary bytes inside of that file, so there must be some way, right? I have a bash script that downloads the windows 10 iso, but the script is not able to alter the iso file, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, you can change arbitrary bytes in the ISO data, but you can't change them arbitrarily. It would be akin to renaming a couple of files on a Linux disk by modifying the appropriate device file under `/dev` directly instead of using `mv`. Depending on the ISO file system, this may be more complicated than changing a couple of strings (one of which needs to be _extended_, which may overwrite data immediately following it).

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I couldn't find a tool that fits my needs. isomaster would be able to do it, but it can't be scripted with bash.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes and that's why I'm looking for a tool that can do all the complicated stuff for me. Just like isomaster does, but with a commandline interface.

Comment: I actually managed to find a way to rename files within an iso file. There is a c library called [bkisofs](https://github.com/aksalj/bkisofs) which is capable of adding, removing, renaming, extracting etc files from iso files. Unfortunately it doesn't support the UDF file system which is used by windows iso images. So I kinda just wasted my time on that. Here is the code anyway: https://pastebin.com/YivnCtjR

Comment: The UDF file system is read-write. You can make a UDF file system on a hard disk and mount it read write on Linux. You can also loop mount a UDF file system image file read write on Linux, possibly also on other operating systems.

Comment: @JohanMyréen That would be amazing. But I can't seem to figure out how to mount it as read/write: `sudo mount -o rw -t udf ./windows10.iso ./tmp` just results in: `mount: /home/fedora/tmp: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only`.

Comment: The UDF file system supports a lot of options, one of them being the "media type". The `mkudffs` utility provides the `-m` switch with which provides a lot of choices, one being `cd`. I could replicate your error message with this media type, so I guess the UDF file system in your ISO file was created to be read-only. Sorry to get your hopes up.